# Fixing Python Indentation When Including in a Method or a Class

Tags: python, pydev

I'm working with pydev on eclipse, and I'm wondering if there is a way to circumvent the indentation, or at least quickly edit indentation in files.

For example, if I make a handful of methods, but then want to put them under a class umbrella, is there an easy way of doing this in terms of indentation, or do I need to go through them line by line?

Comment: highlight all the code and use tab and shift+tab ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Add that as an answer, as it's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight all the code and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

EDIT: You can also highlight the code, right-click on selection, and choose <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>►</kbd> (or to unindent, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>◄</kbd>).

Comment: Done! First post, still figuring things out

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how pydev behaves, but i'm using spyder since a while now, and i can just select all the lines of the unindented/overindented block of code and press Tab/Shift+Tab to add/remove indentation. This can be done even from the options Indent/Unindent from the Edit menu.

If you don't know Spyder, i suggest you to give it a try!
http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/